# connect mongodb remote server to node js app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mean-stack, digital-ocean

I have to connect node js app running on local machine(laptop) to mongodb running on deigtal ocean vps.
I changed bindip in mongodb conf file.
from local machine(laptop) the mongodb connection uri is below:
mongodb://username:password@digital_ocean_server_ip:27017/animal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

db.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const connectDB = async (type = 0) => {
   try {
      //process.env.MONGO_URI is .env var which contains the DB URL
      const conn = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
   });
      console.log(`MongoDb Connected: ${conn.connection.host}`);
   } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      console.log("database connection error");
   }
};

module.exports = connectDB;
```

.env

```
 MONGO_URI=mongodb://username:password@digital_ocean_server_ip:27017/animal
```

app.js

```
//import db.js file in your app.js/index.js/server.js 
const connectdb = require("./db");
connectdb();
```

Comment: err:  MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [1111.111.111.111:27017] on fi
rst connect [Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 1111.111.111.111:27017
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1157:16) {
  name: 'MongoNetworkError'
}]

this error is coming

Comment: mongodb://username:password@digital_ocean_server_ip:27017/animal
have you replaced your username and password with username:password ?

Comment: yes i have replaced. anything need to change on digital ocean mongodb configuration?

Comment: Is your mongod service active on your server?
After starting mongod service you get the same error then, please share the code so I can have more idea.

Comment: mongod service is running digital ocean droplet which i have to connect a node js app running on my local machine(laptop). how to pass droplet or SSH details in the mongodb string. As your code is correct if i run the mongod and node app on same machine. but what if mongod is running on another machine